# Finding a specific element jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so I have this html:

```
<div id="tabs">
<div class="selected"><a href="one"></a></div>
<div><a href="two"></a></div>
<div><a href="three"></a></div>
</div>
```

I have only one div with the class selected which contains a link. What I want to find is the very first link after that one so i tried this jquery

```
var $newTab = $('#tabs div.selected a').find('a').eq(0).attr("href");
alert($newTab);
```

and it returns undefined. How can I find the href of the next a element?

I also had tried this:

```
var $newTab = $('#tabs div.selected').find('a').eq(0).attr("href");
alert($newTab);
```

which returned one so then i tried just changing the .eq():

```
var $newTab = $('#tabs div.selected').find('a').eq(1).attr("href");
alert($newTab);
```

however the result goes back to being undefined.

Comment: you're finding `a` twice.

Comment: I have just updated my question i had written it wrong my apologies

Comment: *"I also had tried this `var $newTab = $('#tabs div.selected').find('a').eq(0).attr("href"); alert($newTab);` which returned one"* Which is correct, according to the HTML you've quoted in your updated question.

Comment: `eq(1)` stands for the second `a` element which is under a `div.selected` no such element exists

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: "How can I find the href of the next a element?..." there's no next "a" element inside .selected class... what exactly do you want to do..?

Comment: if you are trying to get the next `a` after `div.selected` then `var $newTab = $('#tabs div.selected').next().find('a').attr("href");` will do

Comment: I'm making a next and previous button @ArunPJohny

Comment: you need to share the complete code for us to make any sense of the code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find next div of the `.selected` class you can use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
var $newTab = $('div.selected').next().find('a').attr("href");
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R85kQ/)

Comment: @swsa have you seen the fiddle its returning two

Comment: @swsa then your code in your question does not match the code you are using

Answer (score 1):

grab the selected div, then find its [.next](http://api.jquery.com/next) sibling and then get the anchor tag

```
$('#tabs div.selected').next().find("a").attr("href")
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2wZS/1/)

You could also do it with one selector

```
$('#tabs div.selected + div a').attr("href");
```

the `+` is a sibling selector

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2wZS/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the next link, after the selected one.

Try [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) instead of eq:

```
$('#tabs').find('.selected').next().find('a').attr('href');
```

or .next().next() for one after that:

```
$('#tabs').find('.selected').next().next().find('a').attr('href');
```

`eq(0)`, in your test was the only one that worked, because there is only one anchor in the div tag; it's actually unnecessary.

Comment: @swsa You've got bigger problems then.  See my comment on Ram's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use first() instead of eq(n), to get the first item.

```
var $newTab = $('div.selected').find('a').first().attr("href");
alert($newTab);
```

Since there is only one item selected, you don't need to retrieve with index, this should also work.

```
var $newTab = $('div.selected').find('a').attr("href");
alert($newTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var result = $('div.selected').next().find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: why use the attribute selector for a class? this would not work if the class attribute had other classes in it. just use `div.selected`